# scanf is skipped

Tags: c++

I have the following code and I have defined the functions that I am calling here, the problem here is : I run the code 
input: 1
input: 2
input: 2
input: 6
input: 5 6 // for the scanf associated with i=6;
after this I get the output on the screen as 
enter ur choice and then it exits out of the program ... its like the scanf gets the value from somewhere but I dunno from where I also tried fflush(stdin) doesnt seem to work can any one please help

```
int main()
{

  int i,*j,k,pos,val;
  Element *stacka = new Element;

  stacka =NULL;

  while(i!=5)
  {

    printf("Enter ur choice \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&i);

    if(i==1)
    {
      if(createStack(&stacka))
      {
        printf("yes");

      }
    }

    if(i==2)
    {
      k=2; 
      if(push(&stacka,&j))
      {
        printf("yes");

      }
    }

    if(i==3)
    {
      if(pop(&stacka,&k))
      {

        printf("yes %d",k);


      }
    }

    if(i==4)
    {
      if(emptyStack(&stacka))
      {
        printf("yes");

      }
    }

    if(i==6)
    {
      scanf("%d,%d",&pos,&val);
      fflush(stdin);
      insert_at_pos(pos,val,&stacka);

    }

  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the question

Comment: For one thing, `fflush(stdin);` is invalid; it invokes undefined behavior. Who taught you to do that?

Comment: The posted code should really be self-contained and complete so people can just run it and see what's happening.

Comment: You're typing in "5 6<return>" and then your program is terminating? Your scanf() call will only read in the first non-whitespace value, which is 5, so then it would terminate. You'd have "enter ur choice" as the last output because you don't have anything for the i == 5 case.

Comment: @David Heffernan ... I am trying to run the above code ... when I give the input as 6 if goes to case i==6, then there is a scanf statement that takes two inputs and then just exits the program

Comment: @David yeah like mu said, this can't be C.

Comment: @Seth Sorry, didn't spot that. Originally it had both, but so much of it was C like that's the way I went.

Comment: @David yeah I almost changed it to C too. You've been here way longer than I have so I'll ask you: is it ok to have both C and C++ in the tags if the question uses C++ but also a lot of C functions? Or should it just be C++?

Comment: @Seth In my experience, the majority feeling seems to be that you should pick one or the other.

Comment: @David ... I didnt do it ... I know u trying to help me out ... but if u feel so >>

Comment: @koool very odd coincidence then......

Comment: maybe ... but yeah as i said i didnt do it ...

Comment: @koool: instead of repeated `if` statements, why not have a `switch`? just a suggestion...

Comment: Sometimes I wonder about the concern over C and C++ tags - fundamentally this is as much a C question as a C++ question (arguably more of a C question). Having an allocation via `new` really doesn't change that.  The distinction matters in many cases; this isn't one of them. (as a side note - the `new` allocation is immediately lost because it's over written with `NULL`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try inserting a space before `%d`:

```
scanf(" %d,%d",&pos,&val);
```

This will eat any leading whitespace that might be in the input buffer, e.g., the newline from the earlier entry of `i`.

Also, initialize `i` before the loop.

Comment: RESPECT !!! after first few comments I was feeling I was doing something dumb .. thanks I wouldnt be able to figure that out